# TryParse works with var but not with object in C#?

Tags: c#, object, var

Check this out. I want to write the following program: if you input a double or an integer increase it by 1, but if you input a string, append an asterix at the end. So I decided to do a `int.TryParse` and a `double.TryParse`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter something:");
object firstTry = 0;
object secondTry = 0;

bool ifInt = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out firstTry);
bool ifDouble = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out secondTry);
```

In this case both TryParse are underlined, and I get a message that `object` cannot be converted to `int`, which in my opinion is illogical since `object` can be any type... Or, evidently, I'm wrong...

P.S. I dont have that problem when I use `var`, but I still wanna know whats the difference between the two types in this case.

Comment: Anything (everything) is an object, but not all objects are ints, or floats, or strings, or whatever else.  That's why you're getting the error.  You'll need to cast.

Comment: @KevinM1: casts and ref parameters don't play well together.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you *don't* want to do `Console.Readline` twice (you would get two different lines). Instead, assign the result of *one* call to a variable, and then re-use it for the three cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int.TryParse` expects a variable of type `int`, when you specify [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383973.aspx), it is implicitly typed and compiler consider it as `int` because of the assigned value.

See: [var (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383973.aspx)

> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method
>   scope can have an implicit type var. An implicitly typed local
>   variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type
>   yourself, **but the compiler determines the type.**

```
var i = 10; // implicitly typed
int i = 10; //explicitly typed
```

For your `double.TryParse` to succeed you need need `secondTry` defined as:

```
var secondTry = 0d; //or 0.0
```

or

```
double secondTry;
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` is called implicitly typed varables. It is actually a syntatic sugar of c# compiler. Behind the hood it is actually `Int32` in your case.

`object` version fails because `TryParse` expects `out int` as parameter but you're trying to pass `out object`, same thing applies to Double version also.

More info about var keyword can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384061.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an int to anywhere that takes an object because the compiler would automatically "box" the int as an object and then pass that object instead. The other way around is not true. You can not pass an object to anywhere that takes int. For value type, you have to explicitly cast it, for example:

```
object o = 0;
some_function_that_takes_int((int)o);
```

This works fine if o indeed has an int value. However if you have code like this:

```
object o = "hello";
some_function_that_takes_int((int)o);
```

Then it will compile fine but at runtime the code (int)o will throw out an exception because it can't cast a string into an int.

The reason that the compiler can automatically box an int into an object because that will never fail. It doesn't do the other way around because it would fail in the code demonstrated above.

For reference argument, such as ref or out argument as in your code, I don't think you can even use explicit cast. This is because an address of the int value is required.

var will not have any problem because var just tell the compiler to automatically choose a type. In your case the compiler will choose "int". So everything is int if you use var. However if you explicitly define your variable as "object", then your argument is "object" and TryPase wants an "ref int". They are incompatible so it won't work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A declaration on the form `object foo;` declares a reference of `object` type, which can be anything in .NET since all types derive from `object`.

`var` on the other hand is just a way to tell the compiler to figure out itself what it should write there. So `var foo = 7` will cause `foo` to become an `int`. That's why it works with `var` but not with `object` because with `var` the type of the variable is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Your firstTry and secondTry variables must match their respective out parameters:

```
int firstTry = 0;
double secondTry = 0;

bool ifInt = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out firstTry);
bool ifDouble = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out secondTry);
```

In general when declaring a variable that will be used with an out parameter, you have to declare its specific type. If you instead write:

```
var firstTry = 0;
var secondTry = 0;
```

the compiler will infer that secondTry is an int - which isn't what you want. You could of course write:

```
var firstTry = 0;
var secondTry = 0.0;
```

and now the compiler will infer double for secondTry. However I find such code too clever, and prefer to be more explicit when declaring variables used in out parameters.